# QSortFilterProxyModel issue in filtering Real Time Data

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am using qsortfilterproxymodel to filter data from a QstandardModel .I am able to achieve this filtering process in my test application but when i used this in a real time[Integrated] its seems like not working as expected.

**[problem]** : In my case data will be written to a QstandardModel[sourcemodel] every 33ms(approx) ,That means 33-36 rows every 1sec continuously ,But when i use qsortfilterproxymodel to filter its not showing the data as per filter checked(specified) and i also overrided qsortfilterproxymodel's filterAcceptrows() method just to lock a source model before filtering and release source model using QMutex. But i am not able to achieve filtering in real time.

**[Question:]** How to just filter the new rows which is added to a source model not the entire model when new row added in **filterAcceptRows()** method ?

Please help .. Thanks

**ProxyTest.cpp**

```
#include "proxymodeltest.h"
#include "ui_proxymodeltest.h"

QMutex mutex;
ProxyModelTest::ProxyModelTest(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ProxyModelTest)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    secondtext = "SECOND";
    firstText = "FIRST";
    regExp = "\\b(" + firstText + "|" + secondtext + ")\\b";

    model = new QStandardItemModel();
    proxyModel = new MySortFilterProxyModel();
    proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(regExp);
    ui->tableView->setModel(proxyModel);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(updateTable()));
    connect(proxyModel,SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)),this,
                         SLOT(checkInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)));
    timer->start(25);

}

ProxyModelTest::~ProxyModelTest()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ProxyModelTest::updateTable()
{
    static int count = 0;
    model->insertRow(0,new QStandardItem(""));
    for(int col = 0; col < 4 ;col++)
    {
        model->setItem(0,col,new QStandardItem(""));

        if( count % 2 == 0)
            model->item(0,col)->setBackground(QBrush(QColor("yellow")));
        else
            model->item(0,col)->setBackground(QBrush(QColor("lightGreen")));
    }

    if( count % 2 == 0)
    {
        model->item(0,0)->setText("FIRST");
        model->item(0,1)->setText("some text");
        model->item(0,2)->setText("some text");
        model->item(0,3)->setText("some text");
    }
    else
    {
        model->item(0,0)->setText("SECOND");
        model->item(0,1)->setText("some text");
        model->item(0,2)->setText("some text");
        model->item(0,3)->setText("some text");
    }
    count++;
}

void ProxyModelTest::on_firstCheck_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        firstText = "FIRST";
    }
    else
    {
        firstText = "---";
    }
    regExp = "\\b(" + firstText + "|" + secondtext + ")\\b";
    qDebug() << regExp;
    proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(regExp);
}

void ProxyModelTest::on_checkSecond_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        secondtext = "SECOND";
    }
    else
    {
        secondtext = "---";
    }
    regExp = "\\b(" + firstText + "|" + secondtext + ")\\b";
    proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(regExp);
}

void ProxyModelTest::checkInserted(QModelIndex index, int a, int b)
{
    qDebug() <<"in checkInserted";
}

MySortFilterProxyModel::MySortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent)
    : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow,
        const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    bool status;
    mutex.lock();
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    //QModelIndex index1 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 1, sourceParent);
    //QModelIndex index2 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 2, sourceParent);
    qDebug() <<"in filter Accept rows";
    status = sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(filterRegExp());
    mutex.unlock();
    return status;
}

void ProxyModelTest::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    timer->stop();
}
```

**ProxyTest.h**

```
#ifndef PROXYMODELTEST_H
#define PROXYMODELTEST_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMutex>
namespace Ui {
class ProxyModelTest;
}

class MySortFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MySortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    bool dateInRange(const QDate &date) const;

};

class ProxyModelTest : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ProxyModelTest(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ProxyModelTest();

private slots:
    void updateTable();
    void on_firstCheck_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_checkSecond_toggled(bool checked);
    void checkInserted(QModelIndex index,int a,int b);

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::ProxyModelTest *ui;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
    MySortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;
    QString firstText,secondtext,regExp;
    QTimer *timer;
};


#endif // PROXYMODELTEST_H
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

**proxyModelTest.ui**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>ProxyModelTest</class>
     <widget class="QMainWindow" name="ProxyModelTest">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>639</width>
        <height>399</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>ProxyModelTest</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
       <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>30</y>
          <width>481</width>
          <height>301</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>550</x>
          <y>200</y>
          <width>75</width>
          <height>23</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>510</x>
          <y>60</y>
          <width>111</width>
          <height>81</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
         <item>
          <widget class="QCheckBox" name="firstCheck">
           <property name="text">
            <string>First</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkSecond">
           <property name="text">
            <string>second</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>639</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
       <attribute name="toolBarArea">
        <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
       </attribute>
       <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
     </widget>
     <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

Comment: Show your code, it's hard to tell without details. "i also overrided qsortfilterproxymodel's filterAcceptrows() method just to lock a source model before filtering" - not sure what exactly you're doing there in terms of locking, but it sounds unsafe, as filterAcceptRows() won't be the only access to the source model that needs synchronization.

Comment: Show your code, even better, a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry for providing more info late as i was not aware of formatting the code so it took some time :-( ..@FrankOsterfeld  i have edited my question and added code .In the future the updateTable() will be moved to a thread.

Comment: Your example isn't complete (it's missing the definition of `Ui::ProxyModelTest`) and it's far from minimal.  I suggest you make a small example that filters on something simple (e.g. accept alternate rows by integer value) and just outputs to `QDebug` rather than involving a GUI.  Also, I don't see why you have a mutex there, as everything here is in the main thread.

Comment: Hi @TobySpeight .. In the integrated project we will be moving updateModel() to a thread ie will define in some sort of run() inside while(1) . so i added a mutex. At this moment i just need idea how to just filter the row which is newly added ,Not the entire model(sourceModel) again .For eg: If current rowCount is 20 then if i am adding 21st row then it calls **filterAcceptsRow** 20 times .So if i somehow just filter the latest then it will be perfect .Think if there is 2000 rows and fliter acceptrows is called 2000 times just to filter where new row will be added every 25ms. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't compile your code (`ui_proxymodeltest.h` is missing) but I created a reproducible example that you may find useful for this.

My filtering proxy is deliberately simple - it just passes all items that are multiples of five:

```
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
class OneInFiveProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OneInFiveProxyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

OneInFiveProxyModel::OneInFiveProxyModel(QObject *parent)
    : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}

bool OneInFiveProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    return sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent).data(Qt::UserRole).toInt() % 5 == 0;
}
```

Here's a simple class that will emit data we want to put into the model:

```
class Ticker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    const int count;
public:
    Ticker(int count, QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void run();
signals:
    void tick(int);
    void finished();
};

#include <QThread>
Ticker::Ticker(int count, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent),
      count(count)
{
}

void Ticker::run() {
    for (int i = 0;  i < count;  ++i) {
        QThread::msleep(25);
        emit tick(i);
    }
    emit finished();
}
```

Now, let's put those into an application.  We'll run the ticker once, in-thread, and then again, in its own thread:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QStandardItemModel model;
    OneInFiveProxyModel proxy;
    proxy.setSourceModel(&model);

    Ticker t(25);
    QObject::connect(&t, &Ticker::tick, &model, [&model](int i){
            auto item = new QStandardItem{QString::number(i)};
            item->setData(i, Qt::UserRole);
            model.appendRow(item);
        });

    // run it in this thread
    t.run();
    qDebug() << "After first run, model contains" << model.rowCount() << "items"
             << "and proxy contains" << proxy.rowCount() << "items";

    // run it again, but in a different thread
    QThread thread;
    t.moveToThread(&thread);
    QObject::connect(&thread, &QThread::started, &t, &Ticker::run);
    QObject::connect(&t, &Ticker::finished, &thread, &QThread::quit);
    QObject::connect(&thread, &QThread::finished, &app, &QCoreApplication::quit);
    thread.start();
    app.exec();  // will return when the thread finishes

    qDebug() << "After second run, model contains" << model.rowCount() << "items"
             << "and proxy contains" << proxy.rowCount() << "items";
}
```

Running this, I get 25 items in the model each time, and 5 visible through the proxy:

> After first run, model contains 25 items and proxy contains 5 items
>   After second run, model contains 50 items and proxy contains 10 items

A few points to note, and which may help you:

- The model and the proxy live in the same thread.  This is essential so that the proxy can access the source model without any need for locking
- We use signals to allow us to send data that are to be added to the source model.  So the originator of those data doesn't need to be in the same thread as the model.
- When I added a debug line to `filterAcceptsRow`, I could confirm it was called just once for each added item.

Comment: Hi @Toby Speight ,thanks for the points its helping a lot .I have uploaded the `proxymodeltest.ui` which i missed and please run this ,and enable the debug line in `filterAcceptRows` you can see the issue.  i am changing the code as per ur suggestion and thanks for the points and please let me know ur views on this.